# Перенаправление стандартного потока вывода процессу в другом терминале

Tags: linux, bash

Надо перенаправить поток вывода какой-нибудь команды процессу в другом терминале, например `cat`. В свою очередь, он должен перенаправить свой вывод в следующий терминал.
Пути решения нашел, например, [здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/how-to-send-output-from-one-terminal-to-another-without-making-any-new-pipe-or-f).

Пробую. Запускаю процесс:

```
~$ tty
/dev/pty1
~$ cat > /dev/pty2
```

Посылаю сообщение:

```
~$ tty
/dev/pty0
~$ echo "Hi from $(tty)" > /dev/pty1
```

Но моё сообщение я вижу в первом терминале, а не во втором как ожидал:

```
~$ tty
/dev/pty1
~$ cat > /dev/pty2
Hi from /dev/pty0

~$ tty
/dev/pty2
~$
```

Почему второе перенаправление не работает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня так: 
Первый терминал /dev/pts/0,
второй - /dev/pts/1

На втором запускаю cat:

```
# cat < /dev/pts/0
```

На первом:

```
# echo “hi” > /dev/pts/1
```

В результате *hi* появляется во втором терминале.
А в приведенной вами ссылке лучше работать через *proc* и дескрипторы, так как задача передать вывод процессу, а не просто в терминал.

**Update**

Все, что написано выше решает только задачу "отобразить вывод в другом терминале" и не решает "перенаправить поток вывода процессу в другом терминале".
Соответственно, и никакие дальнейшие передачи (по другим терминалам) не получатся.

Как быть?

Мне кажется проще всего это делать через named-pipe (mkfifo) (через несколько каналов, например).
Но если хочется через стандартные редиректы-каналы, то есть вариант написать немного трэша.

Для примера пишем скрипт *echo.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read std
do
    echo "$std +"
done
```

и запускаем его в одном из терминалов (например, в /dev/pts/4) следующим образом:

```
$ cat - | ./echo.sh
```

В другом терминале (пусть будет /dev/pts/0) ищем **pid** процесса **echo.sh**, пусть он равен 23441.
И в этом же терминале делаем так:

```
$ echo "Hi again" > /proc/23441/fd/0
```

Смотрим результат в терминале /dev/pts/4:

```
Hi again +
```

и это означает, что скрипт принял таки вывод с другого терминала и добавил к сообщению "+".

По этой схеме можно передавать в следующий терминал.
Возможно есть и более элегантное решение.

**Update 2. Три терминала**

Сделаем тоже самое с тремя терминалами `pts/0`, `pts/1`, `pts/2`.
Сначала делаем копию `echo.sh` с именем `echo2.sh`.
echo2.sh запускаем в pts/2:

```
$ cat - | ./echo2.sh
```

затем идем в pts/1 и находим pid процесса echo2.sh, пусть будет 31677. Теперь в pts/1 запускаем команду:

```
$ cat - | ./echo.sh | tee >/proc/31677/fd/0 >(cat)
```

в этой конструкции я использовал `tee` только ради наглядности примера, чтобы отобразить будущий вывод в данном терминале. Если задачи отображения нет, то и tee не надо.
И наконец идем в первый терминал pts/0. В нем ищем pid процесса echo.sh, пусть будет 31715, и запускаем команду:

```
$ echo "Hello world" > /proc/31715/fd/0
```

Проверяем результат в остальных терминалах.
Во втором будет `Hello world +`, в третьем - `Hello world + +`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Так и у меня на втором Hi появляется, а хотелось бы на третьем.

Comment: @simpleCode Да, не учел третий терминал. Но это и не важно, т.к. все эти команды `cat` не имеют смысла и не решают задачи. Надо будет подумать...

Comment: Попробовал, пока не получилось. До третьего терминала не доходит. Возможно через fifo будет действительно  проще.

Comment: @simpleCode добавил в ответ Update 2 для 3-х терминалов.

Answer (score 0):

С *named pipe* задача решается гораздо проще:

```
~$ mkfifo firstpipe lastpipe
```

В первом окне терминала:

```
~$ echo "Hi from $(tty)" > firstpipe
```

Во втором:

```
~$ < firstpipe awk '{ 
         print $0" #1"; fflush(stdout); 
         print $0" #2">"/dev/stderr"; }' > lastpipe
Hi from /dev/pty0 #2
```

И в третьем:

```
~$ cat lastpipe
Hi from /dev/pty0 #1
```

Имена каналов, куда будут перенаправлены потоки вывода заранее известны, то есть не надо искать `pid` для редиректа, который к тому же до запуска процесса неизвестен.